# How to use intro.js with Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, intro.js

I want to use [intro.js](http://introjs.com/) for first-time user experience in my Polymer 2 application. Below is the code how I'm trying to use but it's not working out for me.

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="intro.js/minified/intro.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" type="css" href="intro.js/minified/introjs.min.css">

<dom-module id="my-app">
   <template>
      <style>
      </style>
      <p class="line1" data-intro='Hello step one!' data-step="1">Line 1</p>
      <p class="line2" data-intro='Hello step two!' data-step="2">Line 2</p>
      <p class="line3" data-intro='Hello step three!' data-step="3">Line 3</p>
      <p class="line4" data-intro='Hello step four!' data-step="4">Line 4</p>
   </template>
</dom-module>

connectedCallback(){
   super.connectedCallback();
   introJs().start();
}
```

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/amanshu_kataria/pen/oeBwNa) for the same. Since, intro.js is not a polymer web component so, I'm not able to figure out how to use it with Polymer 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work as you have it right now

**Asides**

- If you are importing external styles into a polymer element, you need to use `style-modules` Read [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-modules) , henceforth, preferably.
- The `link rel=import type=css` is deprecated, but If you still want to use them, they should be placed inside your `dom-module` for polymer to shim it.
- `intro.js` , can not be scoped to your polymer element. JS is scoped via IIFE's and you might have to code a wrapper to do that yourself for any external scripts

That is if you strictly want everything scoped.

**Regarding Your question**

The problem is, that intro.js, can not access DOM inside your element.
Hence, it can not reach any of your `P` tags

One solution, is to move / distribute them to an outer scope like the document itself, by using `slots`

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <!-- uncomment this, if you have a style module pointing to intro'scss only-->
    <!--<style include="intro-css"></style>-->
    <slot>

    </slot>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Now, all you need to do is, place all your DOM inside the tags `<my-app></my-app>`

Only then will intro.js work on them. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGt85t?p=preview)

Comment: That was really very helpful :)